# Freezed copyWith method not avaliable for List<T> model in Union/Sealed? (using Flutter with Freezed package)

Tags: flutter, riverpod, freezed, flutter-freezed

How can I get my code (Flutter using Freezed) to obtain use of the "copyWith" freezed feature for updating state here?

Freezed Class:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'todo_list.freezed.dart';
part 'todo_list.g.dart';

@freezed 
class TodoList with _$TodoList {
  const TodoList._();
  factory TodoList({ required List<String> titles }) = _TodoList;
  factory TodoList.loading() = Loading;
  factory TodoList.error([String? message]) = ErrorDetails;

  factory TodoList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$TodoListFromJson(json);

}
```

State Notifier

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:gc_todo/presentation/state/todo_list.dart';
import 'dart:developer' as developer;

final todoListProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) => TodoListNotifier());

class TodoListNotifier extends StateNotifier<TodoList> {
  TodoListNotifier() : super( TodoList(titles: ["first", "second"]) );

  void addTodoList(String newTitle) {
    developer.log("addTodoList - $state");
    if (state is List<String>) (List<String> stateToUse) {
      stateToUse.copyWith();  // STILL DOES NOT RECOGNISE "copyWith"
    };
  }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Freezed uses wrapper types around each variant of your union type, in this case `TodoList`. The "list" variant of that type is not `List<String>` as you seem to be assuming.

Also, [`copyWith`](https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed#unionssealed-classes) only works with properties defined in all union variants, which in your case is none.

You should use `when` to "pattern match" over all variants of that type, or [`maybeWhen`](https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed#maybeWhen) to match a sub-set only.

Here's something that should work in your case:

```dart
class TodoListNotifier extends StateNotifier<TodoList> {
  TodoListNotifier() : super( TodoList(titles: ["first", "second"]) );

  void addTodoList(String newTitle) {
    developer.log("addTodoList - $state");
    state.maybeWhen(
        (items) => setState(TodoList(titles: [...items, newTitle]),
        orElse: () { /* TODO */ }
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: So wondering whether freezed “copyWith” is useful enough to warrant changing ones approach not to use the Union feature in your main model freezed classes?  I think I’ve seen some examples where they use unions for the “status” of a request, and have a separate Freezed class for the model?

Comment: When you use unions, in any language, you have to handle every variant of the union if you want to modify it. Using `when` is how you do it with freezed. Rust, for example, would require you to use `match`, similarly. Freezed does allow you to use common properties of all variants without pattern matching, including `copyWith`, but as you have no common properties that's impossible to generate. The top-level state should not be a union, usually, only sub-leaves of the state, simply because it's very unlikely you have a well-known enumerated set of types as your whole state.

Comment: thanks - just to clarify you're effectively saying (?) that one could have one freezed class to represent state of loading data, to another freezed class that has the data being loaded and it's attributes?  Then you can have use of "copyWith" for the freezed class for the data being loaded...

Comment: I would represent the top-level state as a non-union class that kept some invariants (there's going to be some, probably, like "title" or whatever!) and one or more of its fields could be unions (like loading | loaded | etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
StateInfoListModel ss =
    result.commonMastersModel!.stateInfoListModel!.first.copyWith(
        languages: [
  ...result.commonMastersModel!.stateInfoListModel!.first.languages!
      .mapIndexed((i, element) {
    if (i == 0) {
      return element.copyWith(isSelected: true);
    } else {
      return element;
    }
  })
]..toList());
```

**{
"StateInfoListModel": {
"bannerURL": null,
"code": "pb",
"hasLocalisation": true,
"languages": [
{
"label": "ENGLISH",
"value": "en_IN",
"isSelected": true
},
{
"label": "हिंदी",
"value": "hi_IN",
"isSelected": false
}
],
"logoUrl": ""
}
}**